# How to get the xml response from RestAssured Response

Tags: rest-assured

My Rest API Response is XML, how to handle the response.

My RestAPI code will be as follows:

```
Response res = given()
        .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
        .body("configtype=temperaturesysconfig")
        .with()
        .contentType(ConfigReader.get("application.json"))
        .then()
        .post(ConfigReader.get("config.base.url") + ConfigReader.get("query.temperaturesysconfig.url"));
```

Response will be in `res` variable, i can get the response from as

`res.body().toString()` but it is not coming as xml, the result is as `com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseImpl@4390f46e`.

How to get it as xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try registering XML parser explicitly for the response before you make REST call as shown below.

```
registerParser("application/xml", Parser.XML);

Response res = 
      given()
        .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
        .body("configtype=temperaturesysconfig")
        .with()
        .contentType(ConfigReader.get("application.json"))
      .then()
        .post(ConfigReader.get("config.base.url") +
              ConfigReader.get("query.temperaturesysconfig.url"));

System.out.println(res.body().toString());
```